# Count tag inside different tag with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've got an XML file looking like this:

```
<tier_list>
  <tier>
    <status_list>
      <status>
        <b_list>
          <b>test1</b>
          <b>test2</b>
        </b_list>
      </status>
      <status>
        <b_list>
          <b>test3</b>
          <b>test4</b>
        </b_list>
      </status>
    <status_list>
   <tier>
  <tier>
    <status_list>
      <status>
        <b_list>
          <b>testest</b>
        </b_list>
      </status>
      <status>
        <b_list>
          <b>abc</b>
        </b_list>
      </status>
    <status_list>
   <tier>
</tier_list>
```

I use XSLT 2.0 to transform this file into a csv file.
Is there a way to generate a number, that counts every b-tag inside the tier-tag (ignoring the status-tag)?

So that I would get a result like this:

```
1;test1
2;test2
3;test3
4;test4
1;testtest
2;abc
```

Comment: This is trivial using the `position()` function. Where exactly are you stuck with it?

Comment: I use a for-each loop over every b-tag. I tried different approaches with "xsl:number" to get my desired output. Unfortunately the result number always resets to 1 when the status-tag ends and a new one begins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution, IMHO, is to nest two `xsl:for-each` instructions so that the count restarts for every `tier`. Then use the `position()` function to provide the numbering within the inner `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="tier_list">
    <xsl:for-each select="tier">
        <xsl:for-each select="status_list/status/b_list/b">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>  
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:number level="any" from="tier" format="1;"/>
```

**Demo** (using a **corrected(!)** version of your input):https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRApq

Comment: Ok.. I forgot to mention, that I already achieved this using two for-each-loops. But I was wondering if there was a simpler way, without two loops. But Thanks anyway!

Comment: See the addition to my post. If you have a solution, why not mention it from the beginning??

Comment: I'm sorry! Your demo really helped me a lot. I didn't know the "from" attribute. Thank you very much!